# Search bar value update and search

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a search bar using input field which has a `onkeyup function` which is working properly. I want to add a option that when someone cilcks some text then the search value with be updated and onkeyup will be called that means i want to add a text on search field and and search on that text. The `value is updating` but the `onkeyup is not calling`.

```
class Search extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
           searchValue : null
       }
       this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
       this.onClickChange = this.onClickChange.bind(this)
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            searchValue: e.target.value
        })
    }
    onClickChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            searchValue: e.target.innerText
        });
    }

    search() {
        // working function no need to modify
    }

    render() {
        <input type="text" id="Search" className="form-control" placeholder="Search" onKeyUp={() => this.search()} onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.searchValue}/>
        <span onClick={this.onClickChange}>CUSTOM</span>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to search based on clicked text, you should not expect that `onKeyUp` is called, because this event just called when you're writing some text in the `input`. It's better to use `callback` which exist in `setState` in the `classify` components. So just call your search method in the call back of `onClickChange` when you clicked the text. You can use this way same as bellow:

```
  onClickChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      searchValue: e.target.innerText
    },()=>{
      this.search();
    });
  }
```

Comment: This is a good approach, we are calling the `search` function synchronously after `this.setState` has finished executing (as a callback function).

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that you are expecting `onKeyUp` to be called automatically when `onClickChange` is activated. Normally it shouldn't, as they aren't related events. If you want search to be performed `onClickChange`, then specify this in the body of `onClickChange` function:

```
onClickChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      searchValue: e.target.innerText,
    });
    this.search(e.target.innerText); // sending searchValue as parameter to search function
  }
```

I deliberately sent `e.target.innerText` (the searchValue) as a parameter to the `search` function, since `this.setState` is not synchronous, and will probably finish executing after `search` has been called. I believe you are using `this.state.searchValue` on your `search` function. You will need to modify your search function to get the value directly when called:

```
search(searchValue) {
  // use searchValue here
  ...
}
```

No need for `onKeyUp` on your input, just modify `onChange` like this:

```
<input type="text" id="Search" className="form-control" placeholder="Search" onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e.target.value)} value={this.state.searchValue} />
```

and implement it like this:

```
onChange(searchValue) {
        this.setState({ searchValue })
        this.search(searchValue);
    }
```

This is just one approach, if this doesn't work for your requirements, then please say so and I will edit my answer.

Comment: I tried it without sending parameter but not worked.

Comment: As i mentioned, this won't work without sending the parameter, since state is updated asynchronously and you are using the value before it has been updated.